# What is the most efficient way to match a value(string) in a csv string with Ext-js

Tags: javascript, csv, extjs

I need to match a string from the comma seperated values(CSV) string.

For example : match 'pqr' from string 'abc,def,pqr,xyz'

What is the best way to implement the match with extjs.

Comment: extjs is just a framework. you can do this using javascript, something like this:`text.split(",")[2]`

Comment: use indexOf method to search the given pattern. like 'abc,def,pqr,xyz'.indexOf('pqr',0)